# Can't call method "network" without a package or object reference at blib/lib/NetAddr/IP.pm

Tags: perl, module

I'm trying to write a Perl script to take a list of IPv4 aggregates and another list of addresses and using NetAddr::IP to take each IP and compare to the list of aggregates to see if it belongs to any of the aggregates.  I need to find which ones are not part of any of the list of aggregates I have.

I finally got past all of the Perl errors and now I'm getting some kind of error with the NetAddr::IP module it appears.  Can anyone assist?

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
    Can't call method "network" without a package or object reference at blib/lib/NetAddr/IP.pm (autosplit into blib/lib/auto/NetAddr/IP/compactref.al) line 1075.
```

And here is the code I'm using:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use NetAddr::IP;

    my $fh = ();
    my $sfile = "/home/dkenne201/ex-addresses.txt";
    my $afile = "/home/dkenne201/aggs.txt";
    my @space;
    my @ips;
    my $ip;

    open($fh, "<", $sfile)
        or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
    while(<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        push @space, $_;
    }
    close $fh;

    open($fh, "<", $afile)
        or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
    while(<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        push @ips, $_;
    }
    close $fh;

    for my $netblock (NetAddr::IP::compact @space)
    {
            for $ip (map { new NetAddr::IP->new($_) } @ips)
            {
                    if ($ip->within($netblock)) {
                            print "$ip found within $netblock\n";
                    }
                    else {
                            print "$ip not found within $netblock\n";
                    }
            }
    }
```

Here is an example of the format in the text files that contain the data as well.

Aggs example:

```
    1.1.0.0/16
    2.2.0.0/18
```

Addresses example:

```
    1.1.1.1
    192.168.2.3
    5.2.3.4
```

Comment: `blib`? Why are you using a module you're in the middle of installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `new` twice.

```
for $ip (map { new NetAddr::IP->new($_) } @ips)
```

Your code can be cleaned up to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use NetAddr::IP;

my $sfile = "/home/dkenne201/ex-addresses.txt";
my $afile = "/home/dkenne201/aggs.txt";

my @netblocks = do {
    open my $fh, "<", $sfile;
    my @space = <$fh>;
    chomp @space;
    map {NetAddr::IP->new($_)} @space;
};

open my $fh, "<", $afile;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my $ip = NetAddr::IP->new($_);

    if (my ($netblock) = grep {$ip->within($_)} @netblocks) {
        print "$_ found within $netblock\n";
    } else {
        print "$_ not found\n";
    }
}
close $fh;
```

Outputs:

```
1.1.1.1 found within 1.1.0.0/16
192.168.2.3 not found
5.2.3.4 not found
```

Comment: Thanks much!  Unfortunately I don't have access to install modules on our development box so will have to wait for the admin to come in on Monday to add autodie for me.  But I did try removing the first "new" from for $ip (map { new NetAddr::IP->new($_) } @ips) to for $ip (map { NetAddr::IP->new($_) } @ips) but I still receive the same odd module error for NetAddr::IP.  Anyway, once I have the autodie pm installed I will try your cleaned up code and let you know how it goes.

Comment: [`autodie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) is a core library that automatically handles the error checking for [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and other file operations.  It is not required for this code to work, and could just be commented out, although it would be good to add back your manual `or die` statements then.

Comment: OK so I've removed the autodie and added back the or die statements.  But now I'm seeing something that indicates 0 length from the Lite.pm for NetAddr.  Error message is "Bad arg length for NetAddr::IP::Util::hasbits, length is 0, should be 128 at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/NetAddr/IP/Lite.pm line 1091, <$fh> line 1."

Comment: I tried both versions of the code (original code and your's) on two different systems (Linux and activeperl in Win7) but I get the same error messages on both.  `Can't call method "network" without a package or object reference at blib\lib\NetAddr\IP.pm (autosplit into blib\lib\auto\NetAddr\IP\compactref.al) line 1194.` when using my version and `Bad argument length for NetAddr::IP::UtilPP::hasbits, is 0, should be 128 at ..\..\blib\lib\NetAddr\IP\UtilPP.pm (autosplit into ..\..\blib\lib\auto\NetAddr\IP\UtilPP\_deadlen.al) line 122, <$_[...]> line 1.` when using your code. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the issue.  In my original code and your cleaned up code the variables for the agg file and ips file were reversed.  So it was trying to find aggs within /32.  Once I swapped the `$afile` and `$sfile` variables on the `open` statements everything worked great!  Sorry for not catching that sooner.  And thanks so much for the help!  I'll post the corrected version of the code as well in case others reference this post for a working version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Miller for the improved version of my code.  I am just re-posting with the `$afile` and `$sfile` variables swapped so we are looking for ips within aggs and not aggs within ips (which broke the earlier code in my original post as well).  Works perfectly for me with the below code.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use autodie;

    use NetAddr::IP;

    my $sfile = "ex-addresses.txt";
    my $afile = "aggs.txt";

    my @netblocks = do {
        open my $fh, "<", $afile;
        my @space = <$fh>;
        chomp @space;
        map {NetAddr::IP->new($_)} @space;
    };

    open my $fh, "<", $sfile;
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        my $ip = NetAddr::IP->new($_);

        if (my ($netblock) = grep {$ip->within($_)} @netblocks) {
            print "$_ found within $netblock\n";
        } else {
            print "$_ not found\n";
        }
    }
    close $fh;
```